# Netty - retrieve parameters from the client

Tags: netty

I use a server in Netty and a client in Java. My aim is ti upload files but I do not know how retrieve the HttpContent and the HttpHeader from the httpObject in the method "channelRead0".

```
@Override
public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext chctx, final HttpObject object) throws Exception {
System.out.println("ok ici");
```

How to retrieve the datas to upload a file whose paramters are given by the Http request coming from the client

Answer (score 0):

They already have a example tell you how to do that, hope this example can help you

[HttpUploadServerHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadServerHandler.java#L119)